# Broken Image when uploading images to Amazon S3 with Heroku ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use amazon s3 on my web app but the images are not showing on Heroku. I have setup the correct environmental variables and the AWS region but after the image uploads i get a broken image link. When i log in to my S3 account the image is uploaded correctly and the image is showing but i don't know why it's not working in Heroku. Here's my code:

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),

  }
}
```

**views/colors/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="center">
    <div class="row">
      <% @colors.each do |color| %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="thumbnail">

            <%= color.name %>

        <%= image_tag color.image.url(:medium) %>

        <%= color.code %><br>
       <%= link_to 'Show', color %>
       <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_color_path(color) %>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', color, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>


            </div>

        </div>
      <%end%>
    </div>

    <%= link_to 'New Color', new_color_path %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

Comment: Do you have the rails 12 factor gem installed?  https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor.

Comment: yes i did install the gem

Comment: can you post the code from where you are saving the assets?  Are you adding public read?

Comment: thanks for your help. I actually managed to make it work by changing the region from US Standard to London for the Amazon AWS Region